# how to disable webresource.axd in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, .net, configuration, webforms, webresource.axd

How to remove or disable webresource.axd in asp.net application?

webresource.axd path:

```
http://../../WebResource.axd?d=YmdRSSV5cb_VO9PGgROiUr5ScXlskGklae8QHK2W4v0CsgShDpI-qEXIF2WUBa8PrWRh1ngl6-wiUNhV-nUtyTubQtEzRQCgG7fmTaynX6Uw3GxURyufcjxLFTmwZ_9XIeoNrW_AJ5KYXngED4uG2g2&t=637814851746327080
```